# Model faces the wrong way. Any way to fix it?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a face in Blender and I realized that it was facing the wrong way. When I had started it was facing the right way. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

**LEFT IMAGE** 
[image: Reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the mesh in *Edit mode* by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> on the keyboard and rotate it on Z axis by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> (Rotate) and then <kbd>Z</kbd> (to rotate only on Z axis). Change angle as you want and you are set.

**Press Z only while you are rotating it, or it will switch to Wireframe mode.**

Comment: I can't get mirror working the right direction now?

Comment: Can you attach your blend file herewith.